# How does displaying a single post happens in a loop ?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

trying to understand WP loop, I got kinda lost. Logically whenever there is a loop there is a collection. But, here WP says it displays a single post while iterating through its loop. I understand that WP loop is used when I want, for example, to display all posts, sorted by date, in the front-page, like in [here](http://thecoderider.com/). But how does WP loop work when I want only a single post ?

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <?php _e( 'Sorry, no pages matched your criteria.', 'textdomain' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How come this code outputs only one post ?

**Reference:**
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/#individual-post

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like fetching a single result from the Database Table with a `LIMIT` clause of `1`.
You still use a while() loop, but only one result is returned.

Wordpress then gets the title, content etc of the post using `the_title()`, `the_content()` and [other tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags#Post_tags).

And these tags are just functions that fetch the values from the `post_title`, `post_content` and other columns in the `wp_posts` table.

Eg for other columns: `ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt` etc.

Comment: Ok, but there no difference with displaying multiple posts .... ? https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/#blog-archive

Comment: Nope, no difference whatsoever. While the loop remains the same, you could use the _get_template_part()_ function inside the loop to create custom templates to display the post(s).

Comment: And this is what confuses me ... the loop is the same. What is the thing that tells WP to display only one post in page or display a list of posts ?

Comment: @Adelin *What is the thing that tells WP to display only one post in page or display a list of posts?* The query result of course. If a user is at the index or a category page, the query result will contain all the posts of index or that specific category. If the user have typed some search criteria, the query result will contain the posts matching that search criteria. It's really simple. It is the same functionality as for a single `while(index > 10) { ... }` loop; it will loop while index > 10 and of course the initial value of index does not depend on the loop.

Comment: @ChristosLytras Aha ... now that makes sense.But it is still doesn't make sense to have a loop in place where a single entity is needed ...

Comment: @Adelin it makes perfectly sense. People use that to handle both scenarios of having one post, many posts or even no posts as you can see. And it makes sense because we don't want to write different code for displaying a single element and many elements since the only difference is the number of results. Maybe you are confusing the single post view with the post listing view which is a total different think. This loop refers to the listing view. As of why people try to handle all with one, see this wiki article [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: @ChristosLytras I think that this "Maybe you are confusing the single post view with the post listing view which is a total different think" is actually what I am looking for .... Can you provide some links or explanations ?